# How to run multi-module maven project from GitHub in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

actually I am a newbie and have not a lot experience with Java and Eclipse. I want to try something out like in this tutorial: http://www.jskat.org/develop_de.html

Unfortunately the tutorial is for an older Eclipse version...

It's in German but I try to give the Introductions here in English:

1. Clone the Git-Repository. The URL is https://github.com/b0n541/jskat-multimodule.git
2. Open the Repository and right-click on "Working Tree" or rather "Working directory" and choose "Import projects..."
3. Now I have a problem to understand this point. Right-click on the new project (where I created a project?) and choose "Configure - Convert To Maven Project". Now you can click on the multi-module and choose "Import..." and "Existing Maven Projects" and you can import the submodules of the multi-module as own project.
4. Explanation of the project structure: there are 4 directories. src/main/java; src/main/resources; src/test/java; src/test/resources
5. guide how to implement an AI (that's the purpose of the project)
6. start JSkat. Right-click on the class org.jskat.JSkat and choose "Run as - Java Application" (actually I don't find this class).

I now tried to do these steps. First imported the git repository. After that right-click on working-tree and then use "Import..." and "Import using New Project Wizard" (Version 4.6.2). if I hit the "Maven Project" then "Next", "Next" (checkbutton on "Use default Workspace location"). Choose maven-archetype-quickstart, fill the ID's and click finish. Then a problem occured:

"Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException"

That doesn't work.

Trying something else would be "Import as general project" (selecting the working Tree) and click on "Finish". Then I right-clicked on the project in the package explorer and "Configure - Convert to Maven Project" and "Finish". But then I don't know how to run the project or something.

I'm really new into this, I appreciate some help or introductions :((

(soz for my bad English, I'm a young German student)

EDIT: In this repository is no pom.xml-file. That's why I can't import it just as Maven Project.